# How can I remove all traces of McAfee under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, malware-removal

It is well known that it is pretty hard to remove McAfee from a computer once it has been installed.
Unfortunately my new Windows 10 PC came with a test version of McAfee installed.

I uninstalled it with Revo Uninstaller, which should be more thorough than the Windows uninstaller as far as orphaned files and registry entries are concerned. So I thought every trace was gone.

But this morning after my PC booted I got this message:

[image]

I used [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to find remaining files, and indeed there were some, esp. the following .exe files:

> McAfeeSecurityStartup.exe
>   McAfeeSecurityFT.exe

Trying to delete them doesn't work.

Also, the Registry still contains myriad McAfee, which I started to delete (after making a backup). I gave up after I found that several keys wouldn't let them be removed. I tried this running Windows in Safe Mode as well, but I still couldn't remove files or Registry entries.

One possible explanation could be that there is still a McAfee service running, but I couldn't find it.

Next thing I tried: The [McAfee Removal Tool](https://service.mcafee.com/webcenter/portal/cp/home/articleview;jsessionid=IRCsy0FwSxDA3UhQAjxGw9adgMgu_4mlf0sMx6s-XlggnYL_MFTI!-1155889578!-31457252?articleId=TS101331&_afrLoop=1245892811491418#!%40%40%3F_afrLoop%3D1245892811491418%26articleId%3DTS101331%26centerWidth%3D100%2525%26leftWidth%3D0%2525%26rightWidth%3D0%2525%26showFooter%3Dfalse%26showHeader%3Dfalse%26_adf.ctrl-state%3D40tcxlnm7_4). Files are still there.

So I've run out of ideas. How can you remove all traces of McAfee from your computer?

Comment: "I uninstalled it with Revo Uninstaller, which should be more thorough than the Windows uninstaller as far as orphaned files and registry entries are concerned." - This is a common misconception perpetrated by the snake oil company behind "Revo Uninstaller", it does exactly what Add/Remove programs does, except in a prettier UI

Comment: The best way to remove the McAfee UWP application is to reinstall it then remove it yourself like any other UWP application.  If this is a new installation, you could also just use the [Refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/1236716/why-is-mcafee-pre-installed-after-resetting-my-pc/1236718#1236718) feature, but it sounds like besides the broken UWP application, McAfee is actually already uninstalled

Comment: @Ramhound: I must differ on Revo, since it does do much more than Add/Remove, and in any case it runs first the product's uninstall.

Comment: @Ramhound Like harrymc says: Revo runs the program's own uninstaller, and then cleans up after it.

Comment: @harrymc Except that's what the "uninstall" button within Add/Remove Programs does. I have had experience trying to remove a broken application, I attempted to use both Revo and Uninstall, the end result was the same process.  The uninstaller would run, fail, in both cases

Comment: @Ramhound: Revo detects left-overs, both registry and files. I see it as one of my essential tools.

Answer (score 1):

To eradicate all startup entries belonging to McAfee, use the free
[autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Go on the Everything tab, then use the menu Entry/Find with the string "McAfee".
You may delete (carefully) any entry that it finds, then reboot to verify.

Comment: This would indeed find the registry Startup entry that is attempting to start a removed UWP application