# How to check signature of windows signature edition

Tags: windows-10

i 've got a new laptop with windows signature edition. Is there a way to check signature or to check if it is really untouched (as defined by microssoft)?

Comment: No? It's just using a standard Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: but how to check it - is there any way? Or is this only a label "Signature"? How can i check that standard iso was used? In fact on first run windows asked to create a lenovo id account.

Comment: You can't check there is no way to verify if you received a ISO built by Microsoft or Lenovo.  "Windows Signature Edition" is a marketing label.

Comment: You can use the [Refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/1236716/why-is-mcafee-pre-installed-after-resetting-my-pc/1236718#1236718) if you want.

Comment: Ramhound - make your comment an answer and i'll accept it. I know about refresh - but i wanted to avoid it